# Translate a vector based on a matrix on R

Tags: r

I have an indicate matrix, like this:

```
John   1
Ann   2
Ruby   3
Clair   4
```

So I want translate this vector to number with keep order, like this:

```
(John,Ann,John,Clair,John,Ruby,Ann,John,Ruby)->(1,2,1,4,1,3,2,1,3)
```

I don't know how do it with R(without loop).

Please help me.
Thks

Comment: Do a `merge` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right/1300618#1300618

Comment: @Hugh, the problem with merge is that it won't preserve the order, even when `sort = F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even in your updated example, you can use `?match` just as @Pascal describes. Just don't match to `LETTERS`.

```
# generate example
df <- data.frame(input=c("John", "Ann", "Ruby", "Clair"), 
                 output=1:4)
x <- c("John", "Ann", "John", "Clair", "John", 
       "Ruby", "Ann", "John", "Ruby")
# 
# if output is indeed just 1:nrow(df)
match(x, df[, "input"])
# if output is different
df[match(x, df[, "input"]), "output"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `factor`, see the documentation using `?factor`.

```
x <- c('John','Ann','John','Clair','John','Ruby','Ann','John','Ruby')
y <- factor(x, levels = c("John", "Ann", "Ruby", "Clair"))

as.numeric(y)
## [1] 1 2 1 4 1 3 2 1 3
```

Hope it helps,

alex

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c('A','B','A','D','A','C','B','A','C')
y <- match(x, LETTERS)
```

[source](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-May/033200.html)

**[Edit]** Modified to take into account Shadow's comment

Comment: No 1,2,3,4 just is example. so A,B,C, D just example. Real is more complex

Comment: Why not just `y <- match(x, LETTERS)`?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to the one by @Shadow:

```
library(doBy)

x <- c('John','Ann','John','Clair','John','Ruby','Ann','John','Ruby')
src <- c('John', 'Ann', 'Ruby', 'Clair')
tgt <- c(1,2,3,4)

x <- recodeVar(x, src, tgt)
x <- as.numeric(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
 df <- data.frame(input=c("John", "Ann", "Ruby", "Clair"), 
             output=1:4,stringsAsFactors=F) #should work with factors also
 x <- c("John", "Ann", "John", "Clair", "John", 
   "Ruby", "Ann", "John", "Ruby")
 with(df, setNames(output, input))[x]
 #John   Ann  John Clair  John  Ruby   Ann  John  Ruby 
 # 1     2     1     4     1     3     2     1     3
```

If you don't need names

```
 as.vector(with(df, setNames(output,input))[x])
 #[1] 1 2 1 4 1 3 2 1 3
```